# How to react when Debugger attaches to app during it's work?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-debug

How to react when Debugger attaches to app during it's work? The only thing I was able to find is `Debug.isDebuggerConnected()` , but I wonder is there any better way than setting this in a loop?
Maybe there is some listener or Broadcast event exists?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?